# Naming Java File with Inheritance to compile

Tags: java, inheritance, compilation, naming

I wanna compile java file but dont know how to name the file, since it has 2 public classes, where 1 class inherits from another. I named the file with name of Superclass, however cmd is giving me an error saying that "subclass is public, should be declared in file named Subclass.java". Can anybody help me to resolve this? thank you

```
    public class Superclass {

    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }
}
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    // overrides printMethod in Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass();
        s.printMethod();    
    }
}
```

Comment: The message tells you exactly what to do: declare the subclass in a file named Subclass.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use separate file for both classes or remove `public access specifier` from `Superclass`. In java ,in same file you can have only one `public` class.

And the class containing `main` method should be declared `public`.

Answer (score 1):

both classes should be in separate files. i.e. Subclass in Subclass.java and Superclass in Superclass.java